# why can't I paint wheight paint when i show the verticies?

Tags: rigging, weight-painting, vertex-groups

I have been trying to rig the blender human base mesh hand for a personal project. It has been working fine, but when I reached painting the tip of the ring finger (bone ring_3), I can't paint anymore. It only works if I hide the verticies which I had been using as reference to keep it even. I have tryied painting in other vertex groupes and it does the same thing, although it didn't before (I did unlock them). I am not very familiar with wheight paint having only used it when following blender guru's dohnut tutorial and while playing around. I have rigged a few mechanical models for which I simply added verts to the vert groups. Does anyone know what is wrong?

screenshots of my project:

this doesn't paint
[image]
this does work but I don't have reference
[image]

As I said I have little knoledge about wheight painting, the button I pressed to see the verts (top left next to *view* dropdown) might have other purposes which I don't know about, I just pressed it to see what it did and thought it was handy.
Thanks ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you think is just showing vertices is actually a selection mask:

[image]

That's why you can't paint everywhere with this enabled. It is meant to be used as a way to paint only on a specific area which you determine with your selection in Edit Mode.

If you want to be able to paint anything while having the mask enabled, <kbd>↹ Tab</kbd> into Edit mode and press <kbd>A</kbd> to select everything, then <kbd>↹ Tab</kbd> back to weight paint mode.

Alternatively, you can enable the wireframe overlay:

[image]

Comment: Just to add to this great answer, you *can* select vertices in weight paint mode, although the tools are more limited than edit and recent version have not been kind to default weight paint selection hotkeys.